# Getting the error text from `urllib2.urlopen`

Tags: python, http, urlopen

I used Python's `urllib2.urlopen` and got a 500 error from the server. How do I find the text of the error? I'm hoping that it has useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, HTTPError

try:
    f = urlopen(url)
except HTTPError, e:
    print(e.read())
```